# Monaca：iOS用アプリで秘密鍵とCSR情報を再作成した場合

Tags: ios, monaca

こんにちは。

MonacaにてiOS用アプリを作成してますが、一度iTunesConnectにリリースビルドしたアプリをアップロードしたあと、秘密鍵とCSR情報を再作成した場合（ディストリビューション証明書は変更なし）、その後ビルドしたものをiTunesConnectにアップロードしても大丈夫なのでしょうか？

ご回答よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

アップデートの申請の話でしょうか？
Androidと違いiOSはCSRを再発行してもアップデートの申請はできます。
下記の場合にのみアップデート出来ません。
(それでも申請する場合は新たなアプリとして申請することになります。)
・BundleIDが変更される
・個人の場合は開発アカウントが変更された場合
・法人の場合は開発アカウントが属する開発グループから抜けた場合
・アプリバージョンが以前より高くない場合
・AppleDeveloperProgramの期限が切れた場合

蛇足ですが、Androidの場合はkeystoreファイルが変わるとアップデートできなくなります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
バックアップをなくしたようなのでどうしたものかと悩んでおりました。

Comment: アップデートの申請の際に、iTunesConnectで「暗号化ファイルを変更しましたか？」と尋ねられるラジオボタンがありますのでCSRを変更された場合は何時ものようにNoではなくYesになるのでご注意を……